# Make AJAX call in AngularJS in Cordova App

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have built an app using Ionic Framework, AngularJS, and Cordova.  In it, I have made AJAX calls to several php files using $http.get(), which works perfectly in a browser, but not within the app.  The app is able to render internet pages through an iframe so the network is working.  I have whitelisted my server where the php files reside inside of the app.js file and using .  Also, in my php files I've added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Any suggestions on how to get this AJAX call to work?

```
.controller('StuffCtrl', function($scope, StuffService, LoadingService) {
    StuffService.getStuff().then(function(data) {
        LoadingService.show();
        $scope.stuff = data;
        LoadingService.hide();
    });
})

.service('StuffService', function($http){
    var myStuff;
    return {
        getStuff: function(){
            return $http.get('http://mydomain/stuff.php').then(function(items) { 
                myStuff = items.data; return myStuff; 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error while working on a hybrid app and then I added these lines in my route config function and it started working

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain=true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

This is to enable CORS.
More info on the same can be found [here](http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/)

Comment: This worked perfectly! I also did 2 other things in concert.  I moved the files to another directory and added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to each php file.  Any of the 3 didn't work alone for some reason.  Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a catch handler to get the error :

```
StuffService.getStuff().then(function(data) {
        LoadingService.show();
        $scope.stuff = data;
        LoadingService.hide();
    }).catch(function(error){
         $scope.error = error;
    });
```

And pretty display the error :

```
<pre>{{error|json}}</pre>
```

This should tell you what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it gave me another route to check on the issue.