# Make AJAX-Calls in Android App with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, angularjs, cordova

I am building an Android App with AngularJS using Cordova.
On startup, I am trying to get a list of objects from a node.js server, 
which is running on 10.0.0.7:3000 (current IP of my localhost).

```
$http.get('http://10.0.0.7:3000/items').success(function(data){
    list.items = data;
}).error(function(){
    alert('error');
});
```

When I start the App, the alert-window pops up twice (no idea why twice).
But if I try the same thing in the Browser of my Android-Phone it works perfectly.
So i thought there would be issues with CORS-Settings. I found a Post ([Make AJAX call in AngularJS in Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989897/make-ajax-call-in-angularjs-in-cordova-app)) with some answeres. So I changed my config to this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){

        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I also found another possible solution, where the `<access origin="*" />` in the config.xml file should be changed to `origin="*"`. Well, that was already set by default.

I can't find any other solutions to this problem, because those two steps always fixed it. In my case however, nothing changes trying these solutions.

Any other ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the api actually being called twice?

Comment: I don't call it twice but I guess this is some Angular-thing, like it executes the code in the controller on start up and when the controller is used in the html file.

Comment: What I actually meant is check browser console and see if there are two api calls

Comment: Yes it's called twice

Comment: both are http GET? I think it is better to create a plunker to help diagnose the issue